# table not found while using db raw in repository in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, model, eloquent, repository

I am using repository for querying day from date.
if i use only db raw then it works fine, but i don't like to use whole db::raw query in repository so i used db:raw where i needed.
when i used it, it shows error like table not found as table is found if that qyery is removed.

```
    <?php
namespace App\Repositories\Api\Order;

use DB;
use Bosnadev\Repositories\Contracts\RepositoryInterface;
use Bosnadev\Repositories\Eloquent\Repository;


/**
 * Class ArticleRepository
 *
 * @package app\Repository
 */


/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: sabin
 * Date: 5/10/16
 * Time: 10:29 AM
 */
class OrderRepository extends Repository
{

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    function model()
    {

        return 'App\Models\Order\Order';
    }

function getAll($id)
{

    return $this->makeModel()
        ->join('tbl_sales as sales', 'sales.id', '=', 'tbl_order.sales_id')
        ->select('sales.date', 'sales.delivery_date', 'sales.total_amount', DB::select(DB::raw("select day(tbl_sales.delivery_date) as day")))
        ->where('sales.client_id', '=', $id)
        ->groupBy('tbl_order.sales_id')
        ->get();


}
}
```

Error:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1109 Unknown table 'tbl_sales' in field list (SQL: select day(tbl_sales.delivery_date) as day)
s same problem.
note: i have used sales.delivery_date too, but it show

I have tried putting table command too like:

function getAll($id)
    {

```
    return $this->makeModel()
        ->join('tbl_sales as sales', 'sales.id', '=', 'tbl_order.sales_id')
        ->select('sales.date', 'sales.delivery_date', 'sales.total_amount', DB::select(DB::raw("select month(tbl_sales.delivery_date) as month from tbl_sales")))
        ->where('sales.client_id', '=', $id)
        ->groupBy('tbl_order.sales_id')
        ->get();


}
```

but also it is showing this problem.

ErrorException in Grammar.php line 58:
strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Answer (score 0):

You create an alias to the `tbl_sales` as `sales` here:

```
->join('tbl_sales as sales', 'sales.id', '=', 'tbl_order.sales_id')
```

So I am guessing you should refer to it as `sales` elsewhere, can you try this to see if it helps:

```
return $this->makeModel()
  ->join('tbl_sales as sales', 'sales.id', '=', 'tbl_order.sales_id')
  ->select(
    'sales.date',
    'sales.delivery_date',
    'sales.total_amount',
    // sales here not tbl_sales
    DB::select(DB::raw("select day(sales.delivery_date) as day"))
  )
  ->where('sales.client_id', '=', $id)
  ->groupBy('tbl_order.sales_id')
  ->get();
```

If it doesn't work then my approach would be to get the raw sql and get the query working via sql firstly.

To get the raw sql eloquent is generating you could try the following on your query then `dd()`ing it:

```
$q = $this->makeModel()
  ->join('tbl_sales as sales', 'sales.id', '=', 'tbl_order.sales_id')
  ->select(
    'sales.date',
    'sales.delivery_date',
    'sales.total_amount',
    // sales here not tbl_sales
    DB::select(DB::raw("select day(sales.delivery_date) as day"))
  )
  ->where('sales.client_id', '=', $id)
  ->groupBy('tbl_order.sales_id')
  ->toSql();

 dd($q);
```

or:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

or install https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Once you've got the raw sql of the query you can play around with it in your favourite editor and run it directly on the database until you get the desired results then make the required modifications in elqouent to reflect the correct code.

Hope that helps!

Comment: i have tried it also but it  shows same problem table not found
Base table or view not found: 1109 Unknown table 'sales' in field list (SQL: select month(sales.delivery_date) as month)

Comment: @user2851129 if you can get the raw sql then add it to your question

Comment: I have already used raw query only and it works fine but when i mixed witheloquent then onyproblem occurs..
$articleNews = DB::select(DB::raw("select id,title,description,date_created,day(date_created) as day,dayname(date_created) as dayname,monthname(date_created) as monthname,status,image from articles where (type='news' and status='published') order by date_created desc limit 5"));

Comment: @user2851129 I think you missed my point. I'm telling you to get the sql from your eloquent php code to see what it is generating in order to debug it! Sorry I shouldn't have said raw sql. Difference between using raw statements and getting the sql generated by eloquent.

Comment: it wont reach to dd() as the query doesnt find out the table and it doesnt shows problem in debugger

Comment: Try `Log::info($q)` then check your log file

Comment: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: You don't need the debugbar if you're logging to your log file, try disabling it

Comment: thank you fren!!
i'll use only raw query instead..
I am making api so it don't need webpage and need a token to go to dashboard so i am using postman instead and can't figure out problem